# Why is the cross product of vectors in the given image like this?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors

I know the question seems kind of unclear but why (in the attached image) the cross product like this, I hope someone can clear my doubt.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can the cross product of two vectors be calculated as the determinant of a matrix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133288/)

Comment: Hi Nihar Karve it kind of does but in the image the cross product of the vectors A X B= AyBz-AzBy, I did not understand that part , Thanks for helping out anyway!

Comment: For the record, I recognise this as being from the textbook *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by David J. Griffiths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By distributive property:

$$ \begin{equation}\vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \\ = \left( A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k} \right) \times \left( B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k} \right) = \\ = A_xB_x \hat{i} \times \hat{i} + A_xB_y \hat{i} \times \hat{j} + A_xB_z \hat{i}   \times \hat{k} + \\ + A_yB_x \hat{j} \times \hat{i} + A_yB_y \hat{j} \times \hat{j} + A_yB_z \hat{j} \times \hat{k} + \\ + A_zB_x \hat{k} \times \hat{i} + A_zB_y \hat{k} \times \hat{j} + A_zB_z \hat{k} \times \hat{k} \end{equation}$$

Now, using cross product module definition and right hand rule, see that $\hat{i} \times \hat{i} = 0, \hat{i} \times \hat{j} = \hat{k}, \hat{i} \times \hat{k} = -\hat{j}, ...$ and you will find the expression in the book, that agrees what the determinant means.

Answer (score 0):

It's directly from this

$$\textbf{A}\times \textbf{B} = \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3 \varepsilon_{ijk}\textbf{e}_{i}A^{j}B^{k}$$

where $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol

Comment: Really do you think this answer agrees with the probable current level of the question author ? Moreover, you $i$ must be contravariant if you use $e_i$. And, logically and historicaly, Levi-Civite is after cross product, not cross from Levi.

Comment: Yes, $i$ should be contravariant. Speaking of the level of the question, Levi-Civita symbol is introduced even in mechanics (e.g. Goldstein) and one of the users who deleted his/her comment said this was from an electrodynamics book. It's not something terribly difficult, it can be easily taught even in high school.